# How do I have a unicode source code affect the whole string instead of just the first character?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf

I'm making a simple Roman numeral converter in python and using this:

```
    num_values = [(1000000, 'M'+ u'\u0304'),
                  (900000, 'CM'+ u'\u0304'),
                  (100000, 'C'+ u'\u0304'),
                  (90000, 'XC'+ u'\u0304'),
                  (50000, 'L'+ u'\u0304'),
                  (40000, 'XL'+ u'\u0304'),
                  (10000, 'X'+ u'\u0304'),
                  (5000, 'V'+ u'\u0304'),
                  (1000, 'M'),
                  (900, 'CM'),
                  (500, 'D'),
                  (400, 'CD'),
                  (100, 'C'),
                  (90, 'XC'),
                  (50, 'L'),
                  (40, 'XL'),
                  (10, 'X'),
                  (9, 'IX'),
                  (5, 'V'),
                  (4, 'IV'),
                  (1, 'I')]
```

to represent the values my function iterates through. However, the unicode seems to only affect the first character in a string. (For instance, `'CM'+ u'\u0304'` looks like CM̄ instead of C̄M̄.)

Is there a way to correct this while keeping everything in one index?

Comment: Is there a reason why you refuse to use `u'C\u0304M\0304'`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I tried that previously but I would get  C̄M4. Not sure what is wrong

Comment: Are you *sure* it looks like `C̄M`?  I would have expected `CM̄`

Comment: @MartinBonner Oh sorry, you're correct, I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combining macron (U+0304) combines with the preceeding code-point (only).  If you want two characters with overbars, you are going to need two combining macrons.  Either:

```
'C\u0304M\u0304'
```

or

```
'C' + '\u0304' + M + '\u0304'
```

If you are using Python 2 (don't), you will need `u'\u0304'` or `u'C\u0304M\u0304'`

---

You *may* be interested in the fact that Unicode has

```
                  (100_000, u'\u2188'),   # ↈ
                  (50_000, u'\u2187'),    # ↇ
                  (10_000, u'\u2182'),    # ↂ
```

Unfortunately, there is nothing for 1_000_000, and I don't know how historical they are (it probably depends on when and where you are talking about).  There is also u'\u2180' (ↀ) as an alternative 1000.  (Combining macron would work with that.)